# How create a bridge for relation two web service in C#

Tags: c#, wcf, service

We get a service (web service in C#) from bank and we gave bank a valid IP and bank opened service for us.
That service had some methods and we call methods and get response form Bank.

Now, we should distribute this service to some computer in our networks  that can call methods how to do that?

My solution is creating a bridge service, 
The bridge is a service on our server that can distribute bank's service to our networks is this correct?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

you can rely on MSMQ where the bank service can put data in a private queue inside MSMQ, and from there you can either notify computers to come and read the data from the queue over TCP, UDP ... etc. Alternatively, create WCF service that listens to the queue and transport the data to other computers.